# Forget ssh credentials

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm using an ssh key (with password) to log into a system. It's the default key on my local computer (inside ~/.ssh). I'm using some kind of credential helper (gnome keyring or ssh-agent, not sure which one) so I never have to enter my password when sshing, even after reboot. I want to know how I can make the credential manager 'forget' the cached credentials and start asking me for password again.